# Devise: How to sign in user from sign up form?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `Devise` I would like to replicate the behaviour of the sign-in form from the sign-up page.

Thus if the user exists in the database and the password that the user entered  matches that of a user in the database, the user should be signed in to the application automatically.

1. User arrives to site and completes sign-up form
2. Registration controller realises the user exists in the database
3. Application takes the submitted details and signs the user in

The below code overrides the default registration controller but is as far as I made it.  I have tried all sorts of ways to call the sign_in method from here but it often falls short.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if User.exists?

      Devise::SessionsController.new.create

      # sign_in @user
      # # self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      # set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
      # sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      # yield resource if block_given?
      # respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

      # # set_flash_message :notice, :"user already exists"
      # # sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      # # respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"failed to login"
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: uhm - you want to automatically sign in that user, if provided with an email, that already exists in database?

Comment: @renepaulokat I think the idea is to automatically sign the user in if their email and password both match a user in that exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a great idea when security and user experience is taken into consideration. But...if you really want to you can make sure the credentials (email and password) are correct and then just create the session from that point. The code would look just like how Devise already does it in the sign_in method.